# How to auto resize Datatable column

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset, datacolumn

In our project, we are dynamically creating a datatable during run time with few columns like below

```
 public DataSet LoadAlarmGrid(int Number, bool nodata)
    {
        DataSet dsAlarm = new DataSet();
        DataTable dtAlarm = new DataTable();
        dsAlarm.Tables.Add(dtAlarm);
        dtAlarm.Columns.Add(Properties.Resources.InstName, typeof(string));
        dtAlarm.Columns.Add(Properties.Resources.PinName, typeof(string));
        dtAlarm.Columns.Add(Properties.Resources.DataEnable, typeof(bool));
        dtAlarm.Columns.Add(Properties.Resources.DataAlarmCode, typeof(int));
        dtAlarm.Columns.Add(Properties.Resources.DataAlarmType, typeof(string));
        dtAlarm.Columns.Add(Properties.Resources.DataBehavior, typeof(ALARMSVCLib.tlAlarmBehavior));
        dtAlarm.Columns.Add(Properties.Resources.AlarmDataRealTime, typeof(bool));
        dtAlarm.Columns.Add(Properties.Resources.AlarmDataLatched, typeof(bool));
       <other codes>
    }
```

At the end, the display will have 8 columns.Lets say a column name is 'Instrument'. During loading no issues, all the columns are fit to the size. In case the user is shrinking the column manually. Now the column just shows 'Inst', now the user is double clicking the column to auto resize. But nothing happens.

So the intention is to, when a double click happens in the datatable column, it should auto resize.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to resize a DataGridView.
You can find the sizeing options for DataGridView [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/sizing-options-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control). 

In user resize mode users can make size adjustments by dragging or double-clicking row, column, or header dividers.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add the following code after your `dsAlarm.Tables.Add(dtAlarm);`

```
  dtAlarm.Columns[0].Width = 80;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code solves my issue,

```
            private void grdAlarmData_Resizecolumns(object sender, GridResizingColumnsEventArgs args)
            {            
                if(args.Reason == GridResizeCellsReason.DoubleClick)
                {               
                    GridRangeInfo grid = args.Columns;
                    grdAlarmData.Model.ResizeColumnsToFit(GridRangeInfo.Col(grid.Left), GridResizeToFitOptions.IncludeHeaders);              
                }
            }
```